# Magento 2 - Add additional constructor argument widget block class

Tags: magento2, blocks, custom, widget

I'm trying to create a custom widget by extending the existing "Banner Rotator" widget. Something similar to [this](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-widget/).

I placed the `widget.xml` in my module and created a class extending `\Magento\Banner\Block\Widget\Banner`. Then my custom widget started to appear in BO and works fine (works just like the Magento widget because I haven't customized it yet).

Now I intend to do some additional manipulations to the rotator using the applied layered navigation filters. To do that I'm trying to inject the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver` in to my class. But it fails with this error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to
>   MyNamespace\Module\Block\Widget\Banner::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver, none given, called
>   in
>   /var/www/html/var/generation/MyNamespace/Module/Block/Widget/Banner/Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/MyNamespace/Module/Block/Widget/Banner.php on
>   line 12

Looks like I cannot have a fourth argument in my class.

My class looks like below.

```
namespace MyNamespace\Module\Block\Widget;


class Banner extends \Magento\Banner\Block\Widget\Banner
{
protected $layerResolver;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Banner\Model\ResourceModel\Banner $resource,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $resolver
)
{
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $resource,
        []
    );
    $this->layerResolver = $resolver;
}
}
```

How do I add the 4th argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to delete **var/generation** folder because every time when you construct new class in **__construct()** function. Magento 2 create **Interceptor.php** with constucted class.

For example you have controller at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/MyController.php

For this controller Magento 2 create **Interceptor.php** at

> var/generation/Vendor/Module/Controller/MyController/Interceptor.php

So when you refresh second time Magento 2 look for construct class in **Interceptor.php**. So when you construct new class in controller you need to delete old constructed class in **var/generation** folder manually or by this command:

> sudo rm -rf var/generation/*

Answer (score 1):

Put $data as last variable in the constructor. Any scalar variables should be last.

Comment: This was also a mistake I made but not causing the error I got. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from your magento root folder

Make sure you are in developer mode

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Cleaning auto generated files manually fixed the issue. Basically I had to regenerate the interceptor for the class.